# AngularJS $location.path working on Desktop but not on Mobile

Tags: angularjs, path, location

I have function in **AngularJS** which uses the `$location.path`.
Everything works fine on my desktop computer, however when I tried to use it on my iPhone or Android Tablet it doesn't change the path.

I read to include `$scope.apply()`; after the `$location.path`, this isn't working for me.
Furthermore I included two alerts to see if the function is fired. Alert: Test1 and Alert: Test2 are fired.

```
app.controller('matchesCtrl', ["$scope", "$modal", "$filter", "$interval", "$translate", "Data", "$localStorage", "$location", function($scope, $modal, $filter, $interval, $translate, Data, $localStorage, $location) {
  $scope.BeginMatch = function(c) {
    alert('Test1');
    Data.put('match/umpire/' + $scope.$storage.id, $scope.$storage).then(function() {
      alert('Test2');
      window.navigator.vibrate(200);
      $location.path('match/warmup/' + $scope.$storage.id);
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  };
}]);
```

The path should be changed to `match/warmup/"id"`, but the path stays the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

After more than 4 hours I figured out the mistake. 
window.navigator.vibrate(); is not supported by browsers on mobile devices.
Sorry for the inconvience.